# sliderInput shows on labels datetime but return date

Tags: r, shiny, slider

I would like to have in my `Shiny App` `sliderInput` with `datetimes`. I found out that it is possible to do by `timeFormat` option. I add step (1/24) to jump by 1 hour and on timeline it looks fine, but when I checked what `sliderInput` return I found out that it returns only `date`. It is possbile to get the same value that we have shown on `sliderInput`?

Simply code to show example:

```
rm(list=ls())
library(shiny)

ui <- basicPage(
  sliderInput(
    "slider", 
    "Time", 
    min   = as.Date("2010-12-31 00:00:00"),
    max   = as.Date("2014-12-31 23:00:00"),
    value = as.Date("2010-12-31 00:00:00"),
    timeFormat="%F %T", 
    step = (1/24),
    animate = TRUE
  ),
  fluidRow(textOutput("SliderText"))
)
server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session){
  output$SliderText <- renderText({as.character(input$slider)})
})
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The values in `min`, `max` and `value` should be of type `POSIXct` if you want output from slider to be of datetime. In case of datetime values in slider the `step` then becomes value in seconds so we need to change it to 86400 if we want it to represent a day.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- basicPage(
  sliderInput(
    "slider", 
    "Time", 
    min   = as.POSIXct("2010-12-31 00:00:00", tz = "UTC"),
    max   = as.POSIXct("2014-12-31 23:00:00", tz = "UTC"),
    value = as.POSIXct("2010-12-31 00:00:00", tz = "UTC"),
    step = 86400,
    animate = TRUE
  ),
  fluidRow(textOutput("SliderText"))
)

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session){
  output$SliderText <- renderText({format(input$slider, "%F %T")})
})

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Note that `input$slider` returns output of type `POSIXct`. However, when you have time as `00:00:00` then it is not displayed by default(Try `as.POSIXct("2010-12-31 00:00:00", tz = "UTC")`). To avoid that we are using `format` which will show `00:00:00` in time but will return output of type character.